# 301 редирект с www на без www с учетом https не работает, почему?

Tags: .htaccess, https, redirect, http-status-code-301

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule (.*) https://site.ru/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule .* ./index.php [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Нужно чтобы при вводе www.site.ru переадресовывало на site.ru c https
Приведенный выше код по какой-то причине переадресацию не производит. Если ввести https://www.site.ru то все равно переходит на https://www.site.ru, а надо чтоб по 301-й переадресации переходило на https://site.ru и так же при вводе http://www.site.ru переадресовывало на https://site.ru, и при http://site.ru на https://site.ru
Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Держите, только вынесите эти правила вверх файла:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

С вашего файла возьмите только эти строки

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule .* ./index.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: А при этом что-то убирать из моего кода нужно?

Comment: @Arcadiy обновил ответ, по идее ничего не забыл

Comment: Ярослав, не работает(

Comment: Попробуйте с другого браузера или анонимного, может закешировалось, хотя вроде бы не должно быть такого. Что не работает то? Редирект или вообще сайт теперь?

Comment: У меня работают все редиректы, но сайт сам не доступен.

Comment: все переадресации отдают правильный код 301 кроме вот этой _https:_//www.aviareysi.ru_ При проверке на mainspy.ru/otvet_servera Сервер пишет не отвечает