# Редирект - не перенапрявляет физические файлы

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, mod-rewrite

Есть проблемка

Прописан редирект на https версию сайта без www ([отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/635146/301-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D1%81-www-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-www-%D1%81-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-https-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83)):

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Все адреса хорошо перенаправляет

```
site/category
site/category/article.html
```

Но почему-то не перенаправляет реальные физические файлы, они доступны и по http (и даже с www):

```
http://site/image.jpg (status code 200)
http://site/robots.txt (status code 200)
http://www.site/robots.txt  (status code 200)
```

Где я ошибся?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу предположить, что у вас установлено apache + nginx и соответственно, за обработку статики вам нужно настроить редирект nginx.
Соответственно, смотрите - 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42448439/how-to-redirect-static-files-requests-to-https-in-nginx

Comment: да, вроде стоит, короче стоит обратиться к хостеру чтобы добавил в конфиги? у меня же нет доступа туда

Comment: да, стоит написать хостеру.